# Ping error ipv6

Tags: ipv6, ping

I am able to ping a PC1 to R1, Pc2 to r2 and PC3 to R3. All routers can ping each other. PC's can also ping themselves but I can't ping different PC's, I also cannot ping a PC to their own Gateway. Can someone please help me?

PC1

```
IPv6 address: 2001:DB8:1:1::F

Link Local Ad: FE80::2D0:58FF:FE8A:9EC8

IPv6 gateway: FE80::1
```

---

Pc2

```
IPv6 address: 2001:DB8:1:2::F

Link Local Ad: FE80::201:C9FF:FEDE:4535

IPv6 gateway: FE80::2
```

---

PC3

```
IPv6 address: 2001:DB8:1:3::F

Link Local Ad: FE80::201:43FF:FE7E:2414

IPv6 gateway: FE80::3
```

---

Router1

```
R1#show ipv6 route

IPv6 Routing Table - 8 entries


C 2001:DB8:1:1::/64 [0/0]

via ::, FastEthernet0/0

L 2001:DB8:1:1::1/128 [0/0]

via ::, FastEthernet0/0

S 2001:DB8:1:2::/64 [1/0]

via 2001:DB8:1:A001::2

S 2001:DB8:1:3::/64 [1/0]

via 2001:DB8:1:A001::2

C 2001:DB8:1:A001::/64 [0/0]

via ::, Serial0/0/0

L 2001:DB8:1:A001::1/128 [0/0]

via ::, Serial0/0/0

S 2001:DB8:1:A002::/64 [1/0]

via 2001:DB8:1:A001::2

L FF00::/8 [0/0]

via ::, Null0
```

---

Router 2

```
R2#show ipv6 route

IPv6 Routing Table - 9 entries


S 2001:DB8:1:1::/64 [1/0]

via ::, Serial0/0/0

C 2001:DB8:1:2::/64 [0/0]

via ::, FastEthernet0/0

L 2001:DB8:1:2::1/128 [0/0]

via ::, FastEthernet0/0

S 2001:DB8:1:3::/64 [1/0]

via 2001:DB8:1:A002::2, Serial0/1/0

C 2001:DB8:1:A001::/64 [0/0]

via ::, Serial0/0/0

L 2001:DB8:1:A001::2/128 [0/0]

via ::, Serial0/0/0

C 2001:DB8:1:A002::/64 [0/0]

via ::, Serial0/1/0

L 2001:DB8:1:A002::1/128 [0/0]

via ::, Serial0/1/0

L FF00::/8 [0/0]

via ::, Null0
```

---

Router 3

```
R3#show ipv6 route

IPv6 Routing Table - 6 entries


S ::/0 [1/0]

via 2001:DB8:1:A002::1

C 2001:DB8:1:3::/64 [0/0]

via ::, FastEthernet0/0

L 2001:DB8:1:3::1/128 [0/0]

via ::, FastEthernet0/0

C 2001:DB8:1:A002::/64 [0/0]

via ::, Serial0/1/0

L 2001:DB8:1:A002::2/128 [0/0]

via ::, Serial0/1/0

L FF00::/8 [0/0]

via ::, Null0
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the configuration of the routers.

Comment: make sure that your gateways are properly configured

Comment: Oh, thank you infra! I misconfigured the Gateways

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any dynamic routing protocol, just a few static routes. If you are going to use static routes you  must route all network (that you want to reach) on all routers.

Comment: Please post your static routes for all routers